# Plotting means on histograms created with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet-wrap

I'm making a several histograms using `ggplot2` and `facet_wrap` and would like to plot the mean value on each panel. Below, I create a dummy data frame, find the mean of each facet, and then create the plots adding the mean using `geom_point`.

```
# Load libraries 
library(tidyverse)

# Toy data frame
df <- data.frame(ID = sample(letters[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE), n = runif(100))

# Mean value of each group
df_mean <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(mean = mean(n))

# Plot histograms
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(n)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ID) +
  geom_point(data = df_mean, aes(x = mean, y = Inf))
```

[image]

I used `y = Inf` to place the point at the top of each facet, but – as you can see – it is cropped somewhat. I'd like to nudge it downwards so that it is completely visible. To my knowledge, `geom_point` doesn't have a `nudge_y` or `vadj` argument and `0.7 * Inf` is obviously nonsensical. I also tried adding `position = position_nudge(y = -5)` as an argument to `geom_point`, but this doesn't appear to have any effect. As a workaround, I even tried using `geom_text` and specifying `nudge_y`, but – like the `position_nudge` solution – it did not have any noticeable effect. Is there an easy way of doing this whilst plotting or do I simply need to calculate the `y` value prior to plotting?

Comment: Do you really want it on the top? You can use something like `...+geom_point(data = df_mean, aes(x = mean, y = 0), col="red")` to place in on the x axis using a different colour.

Comment: @AntoniosK Yes, I **really** want at the top. :) There's loads of space up there, so it's much cleaner that plotting on top of other data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are ok with using `geom_text/label()` you can use the `vjust` argument to do this:

```
ggplot(df) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(n)) + 
    facet_wrap(~ID) +
    geom_text(data = df_mean, aes(x = mean, y = Inf),
              label = "Mean", vjust = 1)
```

[image]

I use it all the time for floating percent change or p-values at the top of a panel and you don't have to calculate anything, `ggplot` has got you.

Comment: I went with this solution using `label = "\U2022"` to produce a point.

Answer (score 4):

```
# Load libraries 
library(tidyverse)

# Toy data frame
df <- data.frame(ID = sample(letters[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE), n = runif(100))

# Mean value of each group
df_mean <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(mean = mean(n))

# Get max count using the dataframe that stores ggplot info
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(n)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ID) -> p

# Plot histograms and plot mean in the right place
p + geom_point(data = df_mean, aes(x = mean, y = max(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$count)))
```

[image]

The key here is to know the maximum count value, because that will be your top y axis value for your histograms. You can get that info using `ggplot_build` function and use that to plot your points in the right place.

Of course, you can go a bit higher than the max count in case the point falls on one of the bars, like this `y = 0.2 + max(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$count))`